# git push from a remote machine accessed through ssh gives "Permission denied (publickey)" error

Tags: git, github, ssh

To explain my situation, suppose I have PC1 and PC2.

I have a git repo in PC2, and I've set up a ssh key so I won't have to enter my credentials when doing git push. Anyways, when I git push from PC2, it works perfectly well.

Now, if I ssh from PC1 into PC2, I can edit files and git add and commit perfectly well. But, strangely, if I git push, I get an error message saying:
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remot repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

If I go back and git push directly from PC2, git push works again.

Is there a way to do git push through an ssh connection from PC1?

**Edit: As of 01/05/21, I still couldn't get this to work using an ssh connection to github, but a workaround that worked for me was to use an https connection instead: that is, change your remote repo url from ssh to https as described in https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/changing-a-remotes-url, and I could git push from an ssh session. But, it would still be desirable to achieve this directly using an ssh connection to github.**

Comment: I was having the same problem. In my case, I am using an ssh-key pair saved in `~/.ssh/github_key` and `~/.ssh/github_key.pub` (secret and public key respectively). I added the public key to Github as explained in the Github help. This particular key file is being provided to the ssh-agent when connecting to github via an entry in `~/.ssh/config` file: https://pastebin.com/1gV3c99U

Comment: If the above works for you, I can expand it to a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to note that this has nothing to do with Git (except that Git can *use* ssh), and everything to do with ssh and the way GitHub use ssh to figure out who "you" are, when you come knocking.

The details with ssh, and ssh-agent (which you are using in your own answer), get very complicated, but the *principle* is simple enough.  The way ssh works is [using a public/private key-pair](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/public-key-authentication/#key-pair---public-and-private):

- The *private* key is known only to yourself.
- The *public* key is known to everyone.

Anyone who has the public key can *encrypt* a message and send it to you.  You can then *decrypt* the message and see what it says.  In GitHub's case, you give them the public key and tell them that this public key is *your* public key.

Later, you have your computer—whichever one you are using—call up GitHub and give them *the same public key*.  They look up this public key.  Now, *anyone* could send them this public key, so they don't yet know for *sure* that this is *really you*, but they trust, for the moment, that because you gave them *that particular public key*, that you are *claiming to be* yourself.

(To set or add a public key that claims to be you, see [this GitHub docs page](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).  Note that GitHub query your browser to guess which OS you're using, before sending you this page's content.  If you tend to use a Mac for browsing and Linux box for programming work, you'll get the wrong set of instructions by default.  There are clickable items on the page to change the set of instructions sent: be sure to choose the right ones.)

Now, just because someone who phones up GitHub *claims* to be you, does not mean they are *actually you*.  So, having answered the ssh-style Internet "phone call" and seeing this public key, Git will now probe your ssh connection to see if that's *really* you.  They generate a "secret" (random-bytes) message, encrypt it with the public key, and send it to you.  If you have the *private* key, your computer can decrypt the just-generated "secret message" and deliver the original bytes back to them.  Having done that, they will now believe that you really *are* you.

So this is the underlying mechanism: you have a *secret key* and a *pubic key*.  You give out the public key.  Anyone who has it can *claim* to be you.  But you keep the *secret* one secret, and if someone comes along and claims to be you, the entity that isn't sure if this really *is* you—in this case GitHub—encrypt something and challenge you to decrypt it.  If you can, *then* they believe that you are really you.

> Aside: why did you believe that the computer you called up to access GitHub is really them?  What if someone else secretly took over their computers, and the Evil Empire are now claiming to be GitHub?  (The answer is not in this Q&A.  This is just food for thought.)

#### Generating a key-pair

Use `ssh-keygen`.  Currently this at least is common across Linux, macOS, and Windows.  How you find and distribute the public key, having generated a key-pair, differs, but they all use `ssh-keygen` to *make* the key-pair.

#### Where do you store your secrets?

For the above to work, you need to have your computer—your laptop, or whatever—*store* some secret.  But if it's stored, how secret is it?

The ssh system can encrypt your secret data, decrypting it only for use when you type in a pass-phrase.  So one way to protect your secret is to hide it under another secret.  But how do you store and protect *that* secret?  [It's turtles all the way down.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down) ([xkcd version](https://xkcd.com/1416/))

To avoid having to type in this passphrase all the time, you can start up an *agent*.  The agent's job is to remember, temporarily for a while, the secret key, and use it in authorized ways.  Who's authorized, to do what?  Well, that's tricky, and I won't go into much detail yet, but we'll come back to this.

#### What if you have more than one secret?

GitHub do let you store *more than one* public key.  So you can generate one public key per computer and store it there, and each computer can have its own secret key.

If there's a chance you'll *lose* your computer, and you want to be able to revoke that computer's access, giving each computer a separate public/private key-pair is a decent plan.  So, consider doing that.  But it's also possible to have just *one* secret, and use it across multiple computers.

To share a public/private key-pair across more than one computer, you will generally need to copy at least the *public* key to more than one computer (so that they all use the same public key).  You can keep the *private* key private, depending on if and how you use the agent; see below.

Each method has its own advantages and disadvantages.

#### More about the agent

If and when you *do* use an ssh agent, you can and should do one or more of the following:

- have one per *running session on your computer* (which requires defining a *session*);
- avoid storing the private keys on *this* computer, if possible;
- use the agent to unlock some but not all keys, if you have more than one key; and/or
- use your ssh configuration file (typically in `$HOME/.ssh/config) to specify *which public key to send to whom*.

This is complicated and messy, and some of the details of various OSes show through here.  First, let's define a *session*.

Abstractly, the idea behind a session is that it's, well, *you*, at a keyboard, on a computer.  It doesn't matter how many windows you open up.  They're all "you".  If you're on a laptop L, and from the laptop you remotely log in to computers A and B, computers A and B usually need to start new "sessions" for computer-oriented reasons.  Ideally they would not need this, so ssh has a system by which agents—e.g., those on computers A and B—can talk to other agents.  That way, you can start one agent on L, your laptop, and then have the agents on A and B talk to the agent on L to get their temporary access to the right secret key(s).

This really can get very messy.  If you have only one secret key, that at least keeps the complexity levels down, but you might want one key-pair to identify "you at home, not at work" and a different key-pair to identify "you at work, not at home", for instance.  Or, you might want one (or more!) key-pair per host, so that L, A, and B all have different key-pairs, in case one of the three machines is stolen or compromised.  I can't pick the right approach for *you* here.  There's no substitute for thinking about your own situation and deciding for yourself.

Anyway, the main point here is that, if you do open multiple windows on a single machine, you *may* need to tell your different command-interpreters (shells, bash instances on Linux) to *share a session*.  Macs (via macOS) have a very nice system that sets all this up for you automatically when you first log in; Linux and Windows generally don't (though Linux window managers could be as clever as macOS—I just haven't used one like this myself; the Linux systems I use are often standalone machines that I have to ssh into anyway).

#### Environment variables, or how ssh-agent tells of its existence

Note: I don't use Windows, so there is no Windows guidance here.

On a Linux system, you get a *shell*—bash, dash, fish, sh, tcsh, zsh, whatever you like—when you first log in.  If you're running Linux on a laptop, it might have a window manager that does something fancy like macOS, as mentioned above.  The rest of this assumes that it does not.

Processes in Unix-like systems are strictly hierarchical.<sup>1</sup>  Each process has what we call an *environment*, consisting of *environment variables* with *values*.  In the shells we use, we express these with constructs like this:

```
HOME=/home/username
USER=username
TERM=xterm-256color
```

and so on.  Traditionally, the variable names are in all-uppercase, and depending on your shell, they must also be valid shell variable names.<sup>2</sup>  The set of environment variables in any given process are up to that process: it can change them, add to them, remove some or all of them, and so on, once that process has been started and is running.  No *other* process can *change* them at this point: only the original process can do that.  But, now that this original process is running, it can spawn (`fork`-and-`exec`) a *new* process, and provide that new process any environment the starting process likes.

What this means for you, as someone using one of these shells (command line interpreters), is that you can provide, to programs that can run programs that run programs, an *initial environment* setting via some environment variable:

```
$ FOO=bar command arg1 arg2
```

(assuming `sh`-style shell) runs the given command with the two arguments, but *also* sets the environment variable named `FOO` to the value `bar` first.  So the process that runs *`command`*, and any processes it runs, inherit this `FOO=bar` setting.

More concretely, when using Git, we can, for instance, run:

```
$ GIT_TRACE2=1 git status
```

to get some information on what the `git` front end does as it runs the `status` sub-command, and how long various operations take.

This particular form sets an environment variable for the duration of a single command.  To set it for all future commands, up until the shell itself exits (or the value is changed), we use the shell's variable-setting syntax:

```
$ FOO=bar
```

But this just sets an ordinary *shell* variable, so we add one more command:

```
$ export FOO
```

which tells the shell to put that variable into the set of exported environment variables given to every command.  In most shells, you can combine these:

```
$ export FOO=bar
```

which sets `FOO` to `bar` and exports it, all at once.

Now, note that any command we run—`git status`, `ls`, `ssh`, and so on—*inherits* these settings but *cannot change the shell's settings*.  Any changes that some sub-command makes can persist in the sub-command and in commands that the sub-command itself runs, but *as soon as the process exits, all of its environment settings are discarded* (they were part of the process itself, and its entire memory image is discarded).

In other words, no command can *set* the shell's environment directly.  Only the *shell* can set its own environment.  But the trick is that a command can *print shell commands* (or write them to a file or whatever), and then we can ask the shell to *run those commands*.

If we print, for instance, the command `git status`, and ask the shell to run the command we printed, *the shell* will run `git status`:

```
$ eval `echo git status`
On branch master
```

(in my shell window looking at the Git repository for Git).  What if we ask the shell to set some environment variables?

```
eval `echo FOO=bar; export FOO`
```

is a rather silly way to set and export `FOO=bar`.  But if we put these kind of commands into some program's output, and `eval` it, we can get the shell to set and export environment variables, which survive to future commands run from within that one shell instance.

This is what `ssh-agent` does.  It *prints* commands to its standard output.  So, when you start the agent for the first time on some computer—such as after you've logged in and have a single command-line window already up and running with a shell prompt:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

for instance, what `ssh-agent` does is:

- start an agent;
- print the following text (taken from a manual run of `ssh-agent -s`):

```sh
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-ExiC7A6qilWW/agent.11761; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=11762; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 11762;
```

By `eval`-ing the above text, we get our shell to set two environment variables, which survive until the window itself is closed.

---

<sup>1</sup>Modern Linux allows processes to be *reparented*, which makes this less-strict than it used to be, but the inheritance chains are still top-down.  I know this statement is mostly jargon but I have not figured out a good way to really express what I mean here, other than to stick with the text to which this is a footnote.

<sup>2</sup>An interesting trick, with no real value that I know of at the moment, is to export—from code where you can do this, i.e., generally not in a shell but rather in Python or C or whatever—some variable values of the wrong forms: either not in the form of `var=value`, or using a variable name that is unsupported by the shell.  Having set up this "impossible" environment, start a shell, and see what it does.  Some shells may remove these environment variables, some may leave them alone, and still others might do something weird like attempt to sanitize them.

---

#### The flaw in this technique

There's one obvious flaw here.  The agent gets *started* in that window, and prints stuff that makes the *shell* in that window save the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` path name and `SSH_AGENT_PID` process ID.  But when the window is done—when you close it or exit the shell—those saved values evaporate.  If you have set up your shell to *kill* the agent (using `ssh-agent -k`), the agent itself goes away too.  Now there's no agent.

If you wish to use the agent in some other window, you can of course start a new window, which starts a new shell, and then use `` eval `ssh-agent -s` `` again.  That's not great, but it works: you get one agent per window.  Each one needs its own passphrase entered to unlock access to secret keys, which is even-less-great.

The macOS trick is to start an agent when you *log in* to the Mac, *before* starting any Terminal windows.  Each Terminal window then *inherits* the *login-level* ssh settings.  We can emulate this on Linux (somewhat messily) by detecting whether there is an agent running in some existing window, or by starting the agent before starting the X server if your Linux system is configured that way (many are not), or [by starting it from xdm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58503/how-is-ssh-agent-being-autostarted).

#### Agent forwarding

There's one last relatively big hurdle, and that has to do with ssh *agent forwarding*.  If you'd like to keep your secret keys all on one system, such as laptop L, but be able to *use* them on machines A and B after running `ssh` from `L` to `A` or `B`, there is a nice way to do this with *agent forwarding*.

To enable agent forwarding, use `ssh -A` or set `ForwardAgent yes` in your ssh configuration.  This gives the ssh agent on machine A (when you `ssh -A machine-A` from laptop L) access to the ssh agent on machine L.  So now, a process on machine A that contacts the agent on machine A gets passed through to machine L (your laptop).  This way, machine A can authenticate to, say, GitHub, as you, even though machine A has only your *public key* on it.  With machine A having claimed to be you, when GitHub come back to machine A and say *prove it: decrypt this string of bytes*, machine A's ssh agent asks machine L's ssh agent to decrypt the bytes, gets the decrypted bytes, hands them to GitHub, and GitHub now believe that machine A is in fact you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! But, I still cannot extract a solution from it. Suppose I ssh from a Mac laptop L to a Linux desktop A. git push directly from A works perfectly well, but not in an ssh session to A from L. To me, the easiest solution seemed to be agent forwarding, so I created a ssh-key and added it to an agent in L as described in https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent. Then, I used "ssh -A" to ssh into A. But, I still couldn't git push from there.

Comment: Once you're on A, you need to make sure that it sends the right ssh key to github. Use `ssh-add -l` (in the window open on A) to list the current set of keys; if the one you need is missing, use `ssh-add` to add it, so that it can be sent. I'm not sure off-hand how often you need to `ssh-add`: the interaction between the agent on A and the agent on L is a little bit of a mystery to me.

Comment: In my own setup, I tend to have both personal ("me at home") and work ("me at <company>") keys. I put the *public* key for each onto machine A (a work machine), and then use ssh-add to enable the public key there, for instance. To enable access to my own repositories, I also put up my personal public key and can use that one when I need it, using the Identity stuff in ssh. If you have only one key I don't know if you need this much fanciness.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have access to the original key you setup when you remote into the machine. When you ssh into PC2, can you generate another key and register that with the server you're trying to push to?

You'll need to run ssh-keygen in the ssh session and then add that key to your account on the git server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you give me more detailed instructions to do what you suggest? I am not very familiar with ssh keys...

Comment: How did you generate and register the key the first time?

Comment: I can't remember the exact instruction I followed, but I believe it was along the line suggested in https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh.

Comment: see edit. If you're using github, that link you sent will probably have all the details you need for adding the new key to your account. generating the key is easy. just run ssh-keygen

Comment: Thanks! I will post the detailed instruction that worked for me.

Comment: As I mention above, the problem persists in a new ssh session. Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: The below solution worked only in the ssh session where I did it. In a new ssh session, I still encountered the same problem. I will leave this post so other people can chime in and figure out how to resolve the issue permanently.**

Here is a solution that works for me.

```
cd ~/.ssh
```

```
ssh-keygen
```

For the prompt saying "Enter file in which to save the key", you can press enter to select the default filename, or enter the filename you want. Then follow the prompt asking for passphrase.

```
cat [name of the key, such as "id_rsa"].pub
```

Copy the output of the cat command including "ssh-rsa" but excluding your computer name at the end. This is your ssh key.

Then, go to https://github.com/settings/ssh and add the copied key there.

Finally,

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/[name of the key without .pub, such as "id_rsa"]
```

You can verify that you did this correctly by

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

You should get a message like

```
Hi [your GitHub username]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Now, you can git push!